# Reactive extensions and Windows Store Geolocator

Tags: .net, windows-store-apps, system.reactive

Can you use Rx with the [Geolocator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator) class in a Windows Store app?

I've used it for my Windows Phone apps successfully, but I'm having trouble figuring out the arguments/types to pass in to Observable.FromEvent to set up the event subscription.

Virtually all of the FromEvent and FromEventPattern methods indicate that they're designed to work with 'standard' .NET event implementations.

The problem seems to be that the Windows Store event delegate is based on [TypedEventHandler<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br225997.aspx), rather than [EventHandler<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx)

```
public event TypedEventHandler<Geolocator, PositionChangedEventArgs> PositionChanged;
```

Alternatively, is there better way to use Rx with Geolocator besides FromEvent?

Comment: First of all, you should likely be using FromEventPattern. Second of all, you could try using `Interval`, but the events are likely the best way to use the Geolocator.

Comment: It seems to be tricky, as the Windows Store event is typed as TypedEventHandler<Geolocator, PositionChangedEventArgs> - not just Eventhandler<>

Comment: Try something like `Observable.FromEventPattern<PositionChangedEventArgs>(MyGeolocator, "PositionChanged");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
vary query =
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern<
            TypedEventHandler<Geolocator, PositionChangedEventArgs>,
            Geolocator,
            PositionChangedEventArgs>(
        h => geolocator.PositionChanged += h,
        h => geolocator.PositionChanged -= h);
```

Comment: Excellent.. I can see why I didn't figure it out myself :-)